# Labeling count points within dissolved buffers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, buffer, expression

I am using the following expression to visualize with a buffer, the nearest neighbors at a given distance:

```
case when

distance(
  $geometry,
  array_get(
    overlay_nearest(
      layer:=@layer,
      expression:=$geometry,
      limit:=2
    ),
    1
  )
)<0.9

then

with_variable(
    'dista',
        distance(
          $geometry,
          array_get(
            overlay_nearest(
              layer:=@layer,
              expression:=$geometry,
              limit:=2
            ),
            1
          )
),
    collect_geometries (
        array_foreach (
                overlay_nearest(
                    @layer,
                    $geometry,
                    limit:=1
                ),
            buffer(@element,@dista/1)
        )
    )
)

end
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I have developed this expression from the solutions presented by user [Babel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/88814/babel) in the questions [Clustering vectorpoints](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/411260/clustering-vectorpoints) and [Dissolve buffers if the intersection/overlap is greater than 50%](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/460346/dissolve-buffers-if-the-intersection-overlap-is-greater-than-50).

My goal is to label count points within dissolved buffers.

Here is a handmade screenshot of the expected idea of counting points within dissolved buffers:

[image]

**Implementing the solution proposed by user **[Babel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/88814/babel)**:**

For the label, I have adapted the constant buffer radius to a variable buffer radius according to distance:

```
case when 

distance(
  $geometry,
  array_get(
    overlay_nearest(
      layer:=@layer,
      expression:=$geometry,
      limit:=2
    ),
    1
  )
)<0.9

then 

with_variable(
    'radius',
    0.45,  -- change buffer size here
    array_length( 
        array_agg( 
            $id,
            group_by:= array_foreach (
                generate_series (
                    0,
                    array_length(
                        geometries_to_array( 
                            buffer (
                                collect(
                                    buffer ($geometry, @radius)
                                ),
                                0
                            )
                        )
                    )-1
                ),
                intersects (
                    $geometry,  
                    geometries_to_array( 
                        buffer (
                            collect(
                                buffer ($geometry, @radius)
                            ),
                            0
                        )
                    )[@element]
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
end
```

For the label placement properties (avoid text repetitions), I do something messy (copy/paste the same expression and injecting the centroid function):

```
with_variable(
    'radius',
    0.45,  -- change buffer size here
centroid (
        collect(
            $geometry,
            group_by:= array_foreach (
                generate_series (
                    0,
                    array_length(
                        geometries_to_array(
                            buffer (
                                collect(
                                    buffer ($geometry, @radius)
                                ),
                                0
                            )
                        )
                    )-1
                ),
                intersects (
                    $geometry,  
                    geometries_to_array(
                        buffer (
                            collect(
                                buffer ($geometry, @radius)
                            ),
                            0
                        )
                    )[@element]
                )
            )
        )
        )  
)
```

[image]

At the beginning the objective is achieved, but now the problem is the expression performance. For a layer with 57 points geometry, the labeling and the placement expressions needs 3 minutes to finish with an i7 processor (32GB RAM). I think it is too long for a layer with little information.

I would like, if possible, to ask for optimize a little more the efficiency of the first solution.

Comment: Regarding your update, this approach is always going to be time consuming with Geometry Generators, as Babel mentions it's iterated for every single feature and for each feature you are re-calculating entire expression (clustering, buffering, joining) on the fly...  The way I see it you at least need to separately generate and store a cluster ID to each point first, based on nearest neighbour, then generate the geometry based on that (and also filtering the symbol so that it only generates a geometry for the first feature in each cluster ID group).

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on what produces the bottleneck funnel in the solution approach. According to the requirements of my question, the solution proposed by Babel is totally adequate. Perhaps the problem resides in my initial approach to the problem. Perhaps the only solution is to pre-generate the geometries or perhaps there is a totally different approach to solving the problem. I will continue to investigating

Comment: It might help if your original expression was cleaned up a bit. It seems really convoluted - I'm struggling to follow some of it. Why use `make_line()` and then `distance()` when you can just use `distance()` directly on two points? And why use `array_foreach()` - twice - when the `overlay_nearest()` is limited to 1 result? And the `if()` test seems unnecessary, of course the distance to the closest feature will be less than that of the second-closest feature (i.e. `@dista` variable - index 1 of array). But from your first screenshot it appears your buffers are generated lines, not polygons...

Comment: Agreed also. I've cleaned up the `if` test for now. You can see the updated code in my question. At the moment I can't remove one of the `array_foreach()` nor the `make_line()`. However, the expression that draws the buffers is fast. The efficiency problem is focused more on the labeling expression

Comment: Yeah, for labelling I think your best bet is to either use virtual layer or processing tools to generate some kind of id column to differentiate each "cluster" (merged group), to speed up counting and label positioning

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is a bit tricky: expressions work on a per-feature basis, so there is no direct way to only label the dissolved buffer (and any indirect way would be too complicated for the task, an overkill). You can, however, label each point with the number of points inside the same buffer using the following expression. For other options, see my other solution.

*Points labeled with the expression - red dissolved buffers just for visualisation purpose:*
[image]

```
with_variable(
    'radius',
    50,  -- change buffer size here
    array_length( 
        array_agg( 
            $id,
            group_by:= array_foreach (
                generate_series (
                    0,
                    array_length(
                        geometries_to_array( 
                            buffer (
                                collect(
                                    buffer ($geometry, @radius)
                                ),
                                0
                            )
                        )
                    )-1
                ),
                intersects (
                    $geometry,  
                    geometries_to_array( 
                        buffer (
                            collect(
                                buffer ($geometry, @radius)
                            ),
                            0
                        )
                    )[@element]
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: @ Babel, labelling per dissolved buffer can be achieved reasonably easily by using the Geometry Generator placement option (and specifying `Around Point` or `Offset from point`) and using your expression with a couple of adaptations - replace the first `array_length` with `collect_geometries`, replace the first `$id` with `@geometry` and wrap the `collect_geometries` in the `centroid` function. Admittedly, perhaps `centroid` is not the desired placement - also, as discussed, this will be even less performant than the counting expression alone..  but it's proof of concept :)

Comment: @Matt indeed - it's possible, but not very straightforward and, at least to me, a bit too complex for what finally can be achieved much easier - that's what I meant with "indirect way". But yeah, in principle it's possible - feel free to add it as a further solution, will be happy to upvote it :-)

Comment: It's not really worth an extra answer as it handles only the placement, not the core of the question that is the counting of the points. Besides, I just recycled your hard work. If someone comments and specifically asks for it then I will make an answer out of it.

Comment: The best solution in my view would be creating the dissolved buffers as virtual layer and label this - like this it would still be dynamic and update when points are changed. To create dissolved buffers in virtual layers is easy with the query `select st_union( st_buffer(p.geometry, 50)) from points as p`, but it creates one multipart feature and I don't know of an easy way to keep disjoint features separate as you can do when using the buffer tool from Menu Vector in newer QGIS versions.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't a complete answer but might provide you or others some ideas to combine with other suggestions.

Considerations:

- Assumes you are OK with clustering algorithm approach (not necessarily same as nearest neighbour)
- You need to forego a dynamic expression for clustering (which will significantly increase complexity and processing speed - I'm not aware of any way to do it in QGIS other than importing your data to PostGIS and using the `ST_ClusterDBScan()` function)
- This is an alternative to Babel's dissolved buffer tool approach, still uses a processing tool with a static result but lets you change buffer size on the fly

---

1. Use the DBSCAN clustering tool in the Processing Toolbox and set your maximum distance (0.9 metres?) and minimum cluster size (2). Your result is the same layer but with new columns `CLUSTER_ID` and `CLUSTER_SIZE`. If you want, use the Categorised symbology by `CLUSTER_ID` to check that the clusters are defined as expected.
2. Create a geometry generator symbol with Polygon geometry type and generate your buffer with the appropriate expression:

- static 100m buffer, merged by `CLUSTER_ID`: `buffer(collect($geometry,"cluster_id"),100)`
- dynamic buffer based on distance to closest feature, merged by `CLUSTER_ID`: `buffer(collect(buffer($geometry,distance($geometry,overlay_nearest(@layer,$geometry)[0])),"cluster_id"),0)`

3. To limit symbol generation to only one feature per cluster, and excluding points not in a cluster at all, use a data-defined override for Enable symbol layer with the following expression: `"cluster_size" is not null and $id = array_agg($id,"cluster_id")[0]`

[image: click to enlarge]

4. Set `CLUSTER_SIZE` as your label expression, and under Placement > Geometry generator, use the same expression in step 2 and select Geometry type as Polygon. You can configure your label placement like it's in a polygon (e.g. placement mode Outside polygons, Offset from centroid, etc.)
5. To limit label generation to one feature per cluster, go to label Rendering > Show label and use the following expression: `$id = array_agg($id,"cluster_id")[0]`

---

Result (clusters generated with max 10m distance):

5m buffer:
[image]

Dynamic buffer:
[image]

Comment: Excellent and completely new approach that gives an out-of-the-box solution. I really like your proposal of using DBSCAN clustering, and I am absolutely surprised by the exact similarity of the result with the Nearest neighbor based solution and DBSCAN solution. This confirms to me that the results of the project I am working on show a consistent pattern. I consider both solutions, Babel's and She_Weeds', to be excellent

Answer (score 4):

If you want indeed to create one label per buffer, it is easier to indeed create [dissolved buffers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsU7N.png) with the box `Keep disjoint features separate` checked to get one separate feature per "cluster". Then use this expression on the buffer layer to count points inside each buffer:

`array_length(overlay_contains('points',$id))`

[image]